# ASP.NET control with visible=false cannot be used in javascript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, visibility

I have an ASP.NET text control  "FromDate" whose visible property is set to false, but I wanted a client side javascript to be able to toggle the visibility property using CSS properties

```
element1.style.display = "none"; // hides the element
element1.style.display = ""; // shows the element
```

but when I attempt to get the textbox, I get null on

```
  var element1 = document.getElementById("FromDate");
```

When I try the same code with visble=true as the default on the "FromDate" ASP.NET control, it works (although that is not the behavior I need)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to hide this control, you can try CSS like this:

```
<asp:somecontrol id="FromDate" style="display:none" />
```

I think hiding the control with CSS is easier to understand.

Answer (score 20):

When you set Visible = false to a control, it is not rendered.  That means there is no HTML representation of that control sent to the page.  Set the style only.

You can set the style as display: none from server side code like this:

```
FromDate.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "none")
```

Comment: Can events be called when visible is false? Asked for security concern.

Comment: @Ufuk: What kind of events?  JavaScript events cannot be called because there is nothing on the client.  Server side events can still be called (Although the control may have been written such that the events wont be raised if its Visible property is set to false).

Comment: Server side events like button click. If somebody messes with postback, can they trigger those events?

Comment: I've never tried it. Maybe EventValidation would stop it.  Give it a try.

Comment: Important question: can a hacker change the control's value if visible=false?

Comment: If it is not rendered, then a hacker will not have access to it, and therefore cannot change its value.  If it gets rendered on the client (even if the style tag contains "display: none;"), then anyone can change the value.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting Visible=false, set its style.display to none, that way the element is still there for JavaScript to manipulate.